# Linq Expression Decimal Contains method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have a class that essentially converts a grids filter into a dynamic linq expression. The grid contains a simple search that takes a single input from user and I would like to create a contains statement that can be used as a generic search.  However, I can not seem to find a way to create an Expression that I can take a decimal type and create a Contains (like) sql query.

Things I have tried, but to no avail.

**Explicity defining as string**, my intention was that I would be able to use a 'Contains' method off of `typeof(string)`.  However, it fails b/c its knows its decimal type and not a string. `Instance property 'Total' is not defined for type 'System.String'`

```
var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "param");
var exp = Expression.Property(parm, filter.PropertyName);
return Expression.Call(exp, containsMethod, constant);
```

**Creating my own Method for decimal**..it appears that this mentality is not possible because there would not be a way for LINQ to generate a query from this.  LINQ can only use known native methods, does this sound correct?

```
Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(
typeof (decimal), "Contains", new[] {member.Type}, constant, param);

public static bool Contains(this decimal obj, string value)
{
   String _this = obj.ToString();
   return _this.Contains(value);
}
```

Ultimately it should generate the following sql

```
where total like '%43%'
```

and total being a DataType of decimal

I have tried a few other ways but its not looking good, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking Lonq-to-Entities or Linq-to-SQL (or other)?

Comment: Using Entity Framework 5.0

Comment: I'm really confused by this question. You say your first query fails, because `string` has no `Total`. But `decimal` doesn't have that either. The you're trying to call `decimal.Contains()`, which also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Looking at the SQL, do you really want to search the string representation of the number for a substring? Why? And would such SQL even work? Don't you need something like `CAST(total AS VARCHAR)`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you doing there but allow me to translate those lines for you:

```
var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "param");
var exp = Expression.Property(parm, filter.PropertyName);
return Expression.Call(exp, containsMethod, constant);
```

Translated to Linq it would be something like this:

```
x => x.Name.Contains("something") // something is the constant and for example Name is coming from filter.PropertyName
```

That statement above will throw an error since x is parameter of type string and string doesnt have Name property.

Your second statement is also wrong:

```
Expression callExpr = Expression.Call(
typeof (decimal), "Contains", new[] {member.Type}, constant, param);

public static bool Contains(this decimal obj, string value)
{
   String _this = obj.ToString();
   return _this.Contains(value);
}
```

Translated it looks like this:

```
Contains("something", x);  // x is param and something is constant
```

Thought "something" shall be of type decimal since Contains is defined with first parameter being decimal and second parameter being string.

Btw, if you are looking for a string out of decimal you could use Expression.Convert(..).

There are plenty example of Expression.Convert on the internet just ask google.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on the Expression.Property() piece.

Comment: Do you need any futher translations of expression trees?

Comment: That was very helpful seeing the expression built out. Was getting ready to look up your recommendation of Expression.Convert() to see if it is beneficial to what I am trying to accomplish. If you have any examples feel free to post in your answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer for you. Take a look at it. If you have any issues understanding it feel free to ask me. :)